# How to pull the image and title of the product from Amazon?

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I am trying to make a list of products based on the unique product codes of Amazon.

For example: https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B00F2GPN36

Where B00F2GPN36 is the unique code.

I want to fetch the image and the title of the product into an Excel list under the columns product image and product name.

I have tried `html.getElementsById("productTitle")` and `html.getElementsByTagName`.

I also have doubt on what kind of variable to describe for storing the above mentioned info as I have tried declaration of `Object` type and `HtmlHtmlElement`.

I tried to pull the html doc and use it for the data search.

Code:

```
Enum READYSTATE
     READYSTATE_UNINITIALIZED = 0
     READYSTATE_LOADING = 1
     READYSTATE_LOADED = 2
     READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE = 3
     READYSTATE_COMPLETE = 4
End Enum

Sub parsehtml()

     Dim ie As InternetExplorer
     Dim topics As Object
     Dim html As HTMLDocument

     Set ie = New InternetExplorer
     ie.Visible = False
     ie.navigate "https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B00F2GPN36"

     Do While ie.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
       Application.StatusBar = "Trying to go to Amazon.in...."
       DoEvents    
     Loop

     Application.StatusBar = ""
     Set html = ie.document
     Set topics = html.getElementsById("productTitle")
     Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value = topics.innerText
     Set ie = Nothing

End Sub
```

I expect the output to be that in cell A1:
"Milton Thermosteel Carafe Flask, 2 litres, Silver" should reflect (without quotation marks) and similarly I want to pull the image as well.

But there is always some error like:
1. Run-time error '13':
   Type mismatch when I used "Dim topics As HTMLHtmlElement"
2. Run-time error '438':
   Object doesn't support this property or method

Note: I added references from **Tools > References** i.e. the required libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faster would be to use [xhr](https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/) and avoid browser and write out results from an array to sheet

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument, results()
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B00F2GPN36", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        With html
            results = Array(.querySelector("#productTitle").innerText, .querySelector("#landingImage").getAttribute("data-old-hires"))
        End With
    End With
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Cells(1, 1) = results(0)
        Dim file As String
        file = DownloadFile("C:\Users\User\Desktop\", results(1))  'your path to download file
        With .Pictures.Insert(file)
            .Left = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 2).Left
            .Top = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 2).Top
            .Width = 75
            .Height = 100
            .Placement = 1
        End With
    End With
    Kill file
End Sub
```

Comment: Great man and yes, it sure is faster well at least in my laptop. Thanks alot.

Comment: Although it seems quite complicated now that I am checking it than the last one. 
:-|)

Comment: Yes, sorry for being so demanding but is there any way to download the image via the code and resize it to be formatted according to the cell? You know how we attach the image to the cell.

Comment: It’s not difficult as you are simply using querySelector to return the two elements by their ids and storing in an array. Then you can write the array out in one go. Using array and xmlhttp is much faster and reduces overhead from writing to sheet.

Comment: Yes you can write image to cell. I’ll see if I can find a link for you.

Comment: can you please add some text to be pasted in cell in case the image is not available i.e. pic's url is not in the following format:
"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71NU17NRf-L._SL1500_.jpg"

Comment: But the link is like say for the image of the product on the link https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B01H3P9DWA

Comment: that is a different url

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as `html.getElementsById("productTitle")` in vba. ID's are always unique, so it should be `html.getElementById("productTitle")`. Run the following script to get them:

```
Sub ParseHtml()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, elem As Object
    Dim Html As HTMLDocument, imgs As Object

    With IE
        .Visible = False
        .navigate "https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B00F2GPN36"
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set Html = .document
    End With

    Set elem = Html.getElementById("productTitle")
    Set imgs = Html.getElementById("landingImage")

    Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1) = elem.innerText
    Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Offset(0, 1) = imgs.getAttribute("data-old-hires")
End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like the OP made a simple typo: he wrote "elements" instead of "element". Well-spotted!

Comment: Can't believe just for an 's'.
Thanks man you are a life saver.

Comment: BTW can we change the code of image to actual image?

Comment: Sure. Check out the edit. I think you meant to get the biggest one.

Comment: Yes, sorry for being so demanding but is there any way to download the image via the code and resize it to be formatted according to the cell? You know how we attach the image to the cell.