# Open IE, search value in a web page search bar, wait for next page to load

Tags: excel, vba

So currently my code opens a web page, then enters a product code from my spreadsheet into the search bar and navigates to the next page. From here the macro takes a picture from the web page and places it in my spreadsheet.

The problem is when the second web page opens too slowly, I get an image from the first web page.

I have tried running a do while loop like the ones below, but it doesn't seem to work for the second web page.

What can I do so that the macro waits for the second website to load before scraping the picture?

```
With IE
    .Visible = False
    .navigate "https://www.genericwebsitename.com/"
     Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
     Set Doc = IE.document
     IE.document.getElementsByName("searchterm")(0).Value = 
     Sheets("sheet1").range("c4").Value
     Doc.forms(0).submit
     Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
End With
```

Comment: Can we have the url and the code that saves the image please?

Comment: Sure thing, here is the url https://www.talacooking.com/.

stri = Doc.getElementsByTagName("img")(11).src 

This is the line I use to take the image, then it is put into a specified cell.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Could you supply an example search term please? Ideally, you want to look for something unique to the new page which you can loop until is present.

Comment: That is exactly what I want. I want to input a product into the search bar, such as 10B10631, then when then new page has loaded, take the picture of the product. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an id on the product page, associated with the product image) which is not present on the search page. You can use a timed loop looking for that.

I've re-organised the code a little and mostly used [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) to apply [css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) to match on desired elements. This returns a single match and is quicker and more efficient than returning an entire collection and indexing.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetImageLink()
    Dim ie As Object, imageLink As String, t As Date
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.talacooking.com/"

        Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

        .document.querySelector("[name=searchterm]").Value = "10B10631" 'Sheets("sheet1").Range("c4").Value
        .document.querySelector("form").submit

        Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

        Dim image As Object
        t = Timer
        Do
            On Error Resume Next
            Set image = .document.querySelector("#product-image img")
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
        Loop While image Is Nothing

        If Not image Is Nothing Then
            imageLink = image.src
            'download image?
        Else
            imageLink = "Not found"
            'Message to user?
        End If
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**XHR with split on response string**

You could side step the issue and do an [xhr request](https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/) - which is what the browser does. It is much faster and there is no browser opening or requirement for a timed loop.

You pass the productId in query string and get a json response. The right way to do this is to use a jsonparser to handle the response and parse out the image url. There are less optimal ways such as using split.

E.g. XHR with split on response string

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()

    Dim http As Object, productId As String
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    productId = "10B10631"

    Debug.Print GetImageUrl(http, productId)

End Sub
Public Function GetImageUrl(ByVal http As Object, ByVal productId As String) As String
    Dim s As String
    On Error GoTo errHand:

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.talacooking.com/quicksearch?format=json&searchterm=" & productId, False
        .send
        s = .responseText
        GetImageUrl = Replace$(Split(Split(s, "src=\""")(1), Chr$(34))(0), "\/", "/")
    End With
    Exit Function
errHand:
    GetImageUrl = "Not found"
End Function
```

---

**XHR with json parser:**

Function re-written to use json parser. Note that the item in the json of interest,  `JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)("results")(1)("html")`,  is actually html. That HTML has to be passed to an HTML parser to then extract the `src`.

I use [jsonconverter.bas](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas). After installing the code from that link in a standard module called `JsonConverter`, go to VBE > Tools > References > Add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

```
Public Function GetImageUrl(ByVal http As Object, ByVal productId As String) As String
    Dim s As String, json As Object, html As HTMLDocument
    On Error GoTo errHand:
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.talacooking.com/quicksearch?format=json&searchterm=" & productId, False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)("results")(1)("html")
        GetImageUrl = html.querySelector(".product-image").src
    End With
    Exit Function
errHand:
    GetImageUrl = "Not found"
End Function
```

---

**References (VBE > Tools > References):**

1. Microsoft HTML Object Library

Comment: Thank you for this, I will give it a try. But I would like to ask, rather than writing in the individual product code, would writing in the cell that contains the product code yield the same result?

Comment: Are you going to be doing this for multiple ids or just one at a time?

Comment: In the same column? Starting at which row? Will there be any gaps in the column? Where will results go?

Comment: My apologies, I should have explained in more detail from the beginning. So on the first sheet of the workbook, I input a product code in and the sheet pulls information from a price list and shows it all in the same row. Then when I press a command button, all the information is sent to the bottom of a table on the next sheet. In the same button push I want to take a picture of the product corresponding to the code I entered on the first page. The picture should be pasted to column A in the same row as the product information is sent to.

Comment: So code is only ever picked up from one cell? If so, you just switch out the hard coded value for the cell reference which is commented out still I believe.

Comment: I am trying it out, but I am not sure how to actually put the image into the spreadsheet using this method, what should I be referring to the picture as?

Comment: You were using the url before to save pic so use same code as you have the url from my code.

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand how to implement it into my current code.

Comment: My code is basically doing the same thing up to and including stri = ....... If your code was working before then you should be able to continue as is. The code above is doing what you asked in terms of ensuring you have the right picture path. I suggest you open a new question with the next bit where stuck integrating and ensure you include the code that does the saving of the picture part. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56415754/6241235) answer shows you how to download from an url and associate with a specific cell.